# Additional assignment operator with ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it's possible to combine a conditional operator with an additional assignment operator. So if I have a loop like:

```
var list = ""

for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    list += (i = 2 ? "yea " : "nope")
}
alert( list )
```

I'm hoping to get an alert saying `yea yea nope` however it just loops once and gives `yea`. Is this possible, or would I just have to use a standard if/else statement?

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uU9g2/

Comment: seems valid to me...did you try logging it out in the console and figuring out what is going on?

Comment: You realise you're assigning a value to `i` within the `for` loop, right?

Comment: Yeah, I did - it loops once and then exits the loop. Updated post with jsfiddle.

Comment: Even if you fix the test, you won't get "yea yea nope".  You'll get "nopenopeyea ".  First time through, i is 0 (not 2).  Second time through, it's 1 (still not 2).  Third and final time, it's 2. If you want "yea yea nope", then you need to reverse the test - either swap `"yea"` and `"nope"` or use `!=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Yea, I accidentally mixed up the true/false values. I was mainly interested in why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i = 2` is an assignment, not a test.  It sets `i` to 2, which is true, so it outputs "yea".  Then the loop increment `i++` increments `i` from its new value of 2 to 3, after which it's no longer `< 3`, so the loop terminates.

You want `i == 2` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = ""

for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    list += (i == 2 ? "yea " : "nope")
}
alert( list )
```

You need the == instead of the =